# If else statement for document.referrer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I require code for checking where a user has come from or change phone number?

JQuery i have is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var referrer =  document.referrer;
});
```

I need an If Else Statement to see:

```
if (user is from (testsite1.com.au))
   // run referrer

else
    //change phone number to 0438 789 999
```

Please Help

UPDATED CODE SO FAR -----

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var referrer =  document.referrer; 
}); 

var site = 'http://www.tp1.websyte.com.au/';

if(site == true) {
    alert('Came From .websyte site');
} else {    
    $(function(){
        $('body *').replaceText( /\b03 9532 1600\b/gi, '0438 610 584' ); 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: ***Notice***: This question is not too broad, the details were given in the now removed comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check if a user came from your site we can use `document.referrer`, note that this only works when you are moving from one site to another by a link. It will not work if a user typed in a URL website directly.

To change phone numbers on the site is simple. We just look for our phone numbers decribed the the `anumber` class, cycle through them and change there `html` contents to the number you want.

```
var lastUrl = document.referrer;

if(lastUrl.search("websyte") == -1) {
    $( ".anumber" ).each(function() {
        $(this).html("0438765876");
    });
}
```

This means that we first get the last url, call it `lastUrl`. Then if it had "websyte" somewhere in that url we assume that they came from your website. In that case it returns some positive number. If we didn't find it -1 is returned. Only when we didn't find "websyte" is when we cycle through all the `anumber` classes and change their html content to `0438765876`.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/L4Fnp/2/)